# storing uploaded images in react state with file reader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How come reader.onloadend does not execute? What i'm trying to do is store the src of the images uploaded and render a preview when I map through images array in the render method. What needs to change for file reader methods to actually execute?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';
class Uploadimage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: '',
      images:[],
    };
  }

setImages = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let { images } = this.state;
  const imageFiles = document.getElementById("image");
  const filesLength = imageFiles.files.length;
  const temp = null;
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = () => {
  for(var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
      let file = e.target.files[i];
      temp.push(reader.readAsDataURL(file));
    }
    this.setState({
      images:temp
    })
  }
}

  render() {
    let { images } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
          <Input id="image" type="file" multiple defaultValue='no file chosen' onChange={this.setImages} />
          <Button icon='upload' type="submit" onClick={this._handleSubmit}>Upload Image</Button>
        </form>
        {images.map((item,index) => <img src={item} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Uploadimage;
```

Comment: What is happening right now? Any console errors?

Comment: `reader.onloadend` is a callback function for reader.readAsDataURL. Shouldn't your `for` loop be outside it?

Comment: @TomaszBubała no errors, and nothing is happening.

Comment: You set `temp` to be null and then try to use `push` method

Comment: @TomaszBubała ive changed that but the thing is the we never even get into the reader.onloadend function.

Comment: Because your `for` loop with `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` should be after (outside!) `onloadend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll have to move `for` loop logic out of `reader.onloadend` method

Until now I was under the impression that when using react, any form field can be turned into a controlled component, however fileUpload appears to be an exception

See updated code with comments below, I haven't tried this sorry:

```
class Uploadimage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file: '',
            images:[],
        };

        this.fileReader = new FileReader();
    }

    setImages = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let self = this; // unsure if this is needed
        self.setState({ images: [] }); // empty out current images array
        const imageFiles = e.target.files; // document.getElementById("image"); // You may want to avoid querying the dom yourself, try and rely on react as much as possible
        const filesLength = imageFiles.length; // imageFiles.files.length;
        // const temp = null;

        for(var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let file = imageFiles[i];

            reader.onloadend = () => {
                self.setState({ images: self.state.images.concat(reader.result); });
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    render() {
        let { images } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
                    <Input id="image" type="file" multiple defaultValue='no file chosen' onChange={this.setImages} />
                    <Button icon='upload' type="submit" onClick={this._handleSubmit}>Upload Image</Button>
                </form>
                {images.map((item,index) => <img src={item} />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain ```reader.readAsDataURL(file);``` why is this required at the end and how does it effect the files that are inside of images in state.

Comment: ```reader.onloadend``` points to an arrow function which puts result of file reading into the images array. Notice that arrow function doesn't get invoked immediately, rather is "registered" to run once ```reader``` has finished ```reader.readAsDataURL(file);```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of wrong things with your code:

1. `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` is inside `onloadend` callback - it should be outside, so the reader can read files and then call `onloadend` after.
2. `temp` is `null` and you try to use `push` method. Set it to empty array.
3. You don't really need `document.getElementById` in React - use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)